# When I use require_once.php everything is loading fine.. but when I use $(document).ready(function() some pages are not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

When I use $(document).ready(function() some pages are not loading?

The problem does not have in IE but problem arises in chrome?

Can anyone suggest what is the problem behind the same.. Is any conflict arises between scripts..

The following is the content one of the pages which is not loading in chrome when
I use

```
<div class="tabs">
            <div class="sap_tabs">  
                     <div id="horizontalTab" style="display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0px;">
                      <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                          <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-2" role="tab"><span>Today</span></li>
                          <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-1" role="tab"><span>This Week</span></li>
                          <li class="resp-tab-item" aria-controls="tab_item-0" role="tab"><span>Comming Soon</span></li>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      </ul>                  
                        <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                            <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-0">
                                <ul class="tab_img">
                                  <li>
                                    <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>25 th</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>2 nd</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="last">
                                      <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>25 th</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </ul>
                             </div> 
                             <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-1">
                                <ul class="tab_img">
                                  <li>
                                    <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>25 th</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>2 nd</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="last">
                                      <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>

                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>                                             <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                <p>Starts on</p>
                                                    <h5>25 th</h5>
                                                    <p>Dec <br></p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </ul>
                             </div> 
                             <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-2">
                                <ul class="tab_img">
                                    <li>
                                     <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <!--div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                     <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <!--div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="last">
                                     <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <!--div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </ul>
                             </div> 
                             <div class="tab-1 resp-tab-content" aria-labelledby="tab_item-3">
                                <ul class="tab_img">
                                  <li>
                                     <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <!--div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <!--div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div-->
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <div class="view view-first">
                                      <a href=""> <img src="images/pic11.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                                       <div class="info1"> </div>
                                         <div class="mask">
                                         </div>
                                          <div class="tab_desc">
                                                <a href="">View Now</a>
                                                <div class="percentage-w-t-s">
                                                    <h5>97</h5>
                                                    <p>% <br> Want to see</p>
                                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                                                                   
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can anybody suggest a solution for the same

Comment: Any errors in the developer console? Also update this if you can to recreate the  issue https://jsfiddle.net/t843jhkk/

Comment: no error happened

Comment: just my problem is when I use .load() the contents are not loading in chrome but loading in IE

Comment: I know no error happened. The fiddle is what you supplied us. I'll need to be able to recreate the issue before I can help that's why I asked for you to update and save that fiddle :)